# can I add "&" as in value of one field

Tags: php, url, query-string

I asked how can I add "&" in value of one of the params
for example

```
www.example.com/index.php?param1=m&c&param2=value2
```

It this possible ?

I need to get it by the query_str() as
param1=m&c
param2=value2

Comment: **What have you tried? What hasn't worked?** What research have you done to solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> It this possible ?

Sure, but you need to [`url encode`](http://www.blooberry.com/indexdot/html/topics/urlencoding.htm) it:

```
www.example.com/index.php?param1=m%26c&param2=value2
```

In PHP this could be done with the [`urlencode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) function.

As far as decoding the value is concerned, you don't need to do anything special, just read it as you are usually reading GET query string parameters:

```
$_GET["param1"]
```

Answer (score 2):

Just encode the & to `%26` with PHP [`urlencode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) and then use [`urldecode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php) when retreiving the values

Comment: Don't `urldecode`... the web server is supposed to do it for you.